# No attribute to append socket python

Tags: python, sockets, server

I'm creating a simple chat server and when I try to connect a client I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Py Files\chat_server.py", line 47, in <module>
    recive()
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Py Files\chat_server.py", line 39, in recive
    client.append(client)
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 20200

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen() 

clients = []
nicknames = []

def brodcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message) 

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            brodcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            brodcast(f'{nickname} left the chat'.encode('ascii')) 
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break 

def recive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")
        client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        client.append(client)
        print(f'{nickname} joined the chat!')
        brodcast(f'{nickname} joined the chat!')
        client.send('Connected to the chat')

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

recive()
```

I've provided the code for the server because that is where the error is. On the client end, there appears to be no issues.

Comment: it should be `clients.append` the name of the empty is `clients` not `client`. A missing `s`.

Comment: that worked it got rid of that error